# Problema con objeto en Java y metodo retornado

Tags: java, poo, objeto, java-8

Buen día necesito una ayuda con este programa de POO, estoy tratando de hacer una "servicio de salud".Cree dos clases, la primera es de medicamentos que hace la suma total de los medicamentos mediante un menu switch a la variable valort. El segundo, es una clase llamada laboratorios que hace la suma tambien de los valores en la variable valort. Como ven estos menus estan metido dentro de un menu externo que selecciona el servicio o de laboratorios o de medicamentos y se repite en bucle hasta que se termina la facturacion(que es el case 3). En esta opcion 3 al finalizar deberia hacer la suma de los metodos darDatos() de ambas clases para hacer la suma de todo los servicios sea tanto medicinas como laboratorios. Pero al crear el objeto y llamar los metodos en el main, estos valores parecen que se borran en el retornado y al final me dan cero. No se como hacer para que los valores de ambas variable valort se mantengan, mostrando un valor total de ambos servicios.

```
/**
 * Write a description of class pruebaPaciente here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
public class pruebaPaciente
{
 
    public static void main(String[]arg){
        Scanner teclado1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int op;
        do{
        System.out.println("BIENVENIDO AL SISTEMA DE SALUD");
        System.out.println("Tipo de regimen");
        System.out.println("1. Regimen contributivo");
        System.out.println("2. Regimen subsidiado");
        System.out.println("Seleccione su  regimen");
        op = teclado1.nextInt();
        switch(op){
            case 1:
                Regimen unRegimen = new Regimen();
                unRegimen.ingresarDatos();
                unRegimen.setContribucion();
                unRegimen.mostrarDatos();
                int op2;
                do{
                    Scanner teclado3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println(" FACTURACION DE SERVICIOS DE SALUD");
                    System.out.println(" 1.Facturacion medicamentos");
                    System.out.println(" 2.Facturacion laboratorios");
                    System.out.println(" 3. Terminar servicio de facturacion");
                    System.out.println(" Digite opcion");
                    op2 = teclado3.nextInt();
                    switch(op2){
                        case 1:
                            Medicamentos unMedicamento = new Medicamentos();
                            unMedicamento.ingresarDatos();
                            unMedicamento.calcularMedicamentos();
                            unMedicamento.mostrarDatos();
                            System.out.println(op2);
                        break;
                        case 2:
                            Laboratorios unLaboratorio = new Laboratorios();
                            unLaboratorio.ingresarDatos();
                            unLaboratorio.calcularLaboratorios();
                            unLaboratorio.mostrarDatos();
                            System.out.println(op2);
                        break;
                        case 3:
                            int suma;
                            Medicamentos unMedicamentoR = new Medicamentos();
                            Laboratorios unLaboratorioR = new Laboratorios();
                            unMedicamentoR.darDatos();
                            unLaboratorioR.darDatos();
                            suma = unMedicamentoR.darDatos()+ unLaboratorioR.darDatos();
                            System.out.println("El valor de todo sus servicios hasta el momento es :"+suma);
                     
                            
                            
                    }
                }
                while(op2 == 1 || op2 == 2);
            
            break;
            case 2:
                Regimen unRegimen2 = new Regimen();
                unRegimen2.ingresarDatos2();
                unRegimen2.mostrarDatos2();
                int opa;
                do{
                    Scanner teclado4 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println(" FACTURACION DE SERVICIOS DE SALUD");
                    System.out.println(" 1.Facturacion medicamentos");
                    System.out.println(" 2.Facturacion laboratorios");
                    System.out.println(" 3. Terminar servicio de facturacion");
                    System.out.println(" Digite opcion");
                    opa = teclado4.nextInt();
                    switch(opa){
                        case 1:
                            Medicamentos unMedicamento = new Medicamentos();
                            unMedicamento.ingresarDatos();
                            unMedicamento.calcularMedicamentos();
                            unMedicamento.mostrarDatos();
                            System.out.println(opa);
                        break;
                        case 2:
                            Laboratorios unLaboratorio = new Laboratorios();
                            unLaboratorio.ingresarDatos();
                            unLaboratorio.calcularLaboratorios();
                            unLaboratorio.mostrarDatos();
                            System.out.println(opa);
                        break;
                        case 3:
                            int suma;
                            Medicamentos unMedicamentoD = new Medicamentos();
                            Laboratorios unLaboratorioD = new Laboratorios();
                            unMedicamentoD.darDatos();
                            unLaboratorioD.darDatos();
                            suma = unMedicamentoD.darDatos()+ unLaboratorioD.darDatos();
                            System.out.println("El valor de todo sus servicios hasta el momento es :"+suma);
                            
                   
                            
                            
                            
                            
                            
                    }
                }
                while(opa ==1 || opa == 2);
                
                
        }
        
        }
        while(op!= 1  && op != 2); 
        
    }
    

}
```

```
/**
 * Write a description of class Medicamentos here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Medicamentos extends EPS
{
    private int acetaminofen;
    private int loratadina;
    private int losartan;
    private int valort;
    private int cantidad;
    public Medicamentos(){
        acetaminofen = 1000;
        loratadina = 2000;
        losartan = 30000;
        cantidad = 0;
        valort = valort;

    }

    public Medicamentos(int cantidad, String nombre, String apellido, String CC, int acetaminofen, int loratadina, int losartan){
        super();
        this.acetaminofen = acetaminofen;
        this.loratadina = loratadina;
        this.losartan = losartan;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;

    }

    public void setAcetaminofen(int acetaminofen){
        this.acetaminofen = acetaminofen;
    }

    public int getAcetaminofen(){
        return acetaminofen;
    }

    public void setLoratadina(int loratadina){
        this.loratadina = loratadina;
    }

    public int getLoratadina(){
        return loratadina;
    }

    public void setLosartan(int losartan){
        this.losartan = losartan;
    }

    public int getLosartan(){
        return losartan;
    }

    public void setCantidad(int cantidad){
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }

    public int getCantidad(){
        return cantidad;
    }

    public void ingresarDatos(){
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre: ");
        nombre = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese su apellido: ");
        apellido = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese su CC: ");
        CC = teclado.nextLine();

    }

    public void calcularMedicamentos(){
        int op = 1;
        do{         
            Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Menu de medicamentos");
            System.out.println("1.Acetaminfen");
            System.out.println("2.Loratadina");
            System.out.println("3.Losartan");
            System.out.println("4.Terminar facturacion");
            System.out.println("Ingrese medicamento a facturar");
            op = teclado.nextInt();
            switch(op){
                case 1: 
                    Scanner teclado1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Ingrese cantidad de tabletas");
                    cantidad = teclado.nextInt();
                    valort = (acetaminofen*cantidad) + valort;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Scanner teclado2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Ingrese cantidad de tabletas");
                    cantidad = teclado.nextInt();
                    valort = (loratadina*cantidad) + valort;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Scanner teclado3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Ingrese cantidad de tabletas");
                    cantidad = teclado.nextInt();
                    valort = (losartan*cantidad) + valort;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("!Se termino la facturacion de medicamentos");
                    valort = valort;
            }

        }
        while(op == 1 || op == 2 || op == 3);
    }
     public int darDatos(){
        return valort;
       
    }

    public void mostrarDatos(){
        System.out.println("El paciente "+nombre+" "+apellido+" identificado con CC: "+CC+" Tuvo un costo total de: $" +valort+" en sus medicamentos");
    }
   
}
```

```
/**
 * Write a description of class Laboratorios here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Laboratorios extends EPS
{
    private  int cantidad;
    private int colesterolAlt;
    private int colesterolBaj;
    private int triglicerios;
    private int hemogoblina;
    private int valort;
    public Laboratorios(){
        cantidad  = 0;
        colesterolAlt =19000;
        colesterolBaj = 22000;
        triglicerios = 11000;
        hemogoblina = 45000;
        valort = valort;
        
    }
    public Laboratorios(String nombre, String appelido, String CC, int caridad){
        super();
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }
    public void setCantidad(int cantidad){
        this.cantidad = cantidad;        
    }
    public int getCantidad(){
        return cantidad;
    }
    public void ingresarDatos(){
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre: ");
        nombre = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese su apellido: ");
        apellido = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese su CC: ");
        CC = teclado.nextLine();
    }
    public void calcularLaboratorios(){
        int op = 1;
        do{         
            Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Menu de medicamentos");
            System.out.println("1.Colesterol alto");
            System.out.println("2.Colesterol bajo");
            System.out.println("3.Triglicerios");
            System.out.println("4.Hemoglobina");
            System.out.println("5.Terminar facturacion");
            System.out.println("Ingrese medicamento a facturar");
            op = teclado.nextInt();           
               switch(op){
                case 1: 
                     Scanner teclado1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                     System.out.println("Ingrese cantidad del laboratorio");
                     cantidad = teclado.nextInt();
                     valort = (colesterolAlt*cantidad) + valort;                   
                break;
                case 2:
                    Scanner teclado2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Ingrese cantidad del laboratorio");
                    cantidad = teclado.nextInt();
                    valort = (colesterolBaj*cantidad) + valort;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Scanner teclado3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Ingrese cantidad del laboratorio");
                    cantidad = teclado.nextInt();
                    valort = (triglicerios*cantidad) + valort;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Scanner teclado4 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Ingrese cantidad del laboratorio");
                    cantidad = teclado.nextInt();
                    valort = (hemogoblina*cantidad) + valort;
                break;          
                case 5:
                System.out.println("!Se termino la facturacion de medicamentos");
                valort = valort;

            }

        }
        while(op == 1 || op == 2 || op == 3|| op == 4);
        
    }
    public int darDatos(){
        return valort;    
    }
    public void mostrarDatos(){
        System.out.println("El paciente "+nombre+" "+apellido+" identificado con CC: "+CC+" Tuvo un costo total de: $" +valort+" en sus laboratorios");
    }
   
}
```

Comment: no se borran, en realidad vos estas creando nuevos objetos en el case 3 que los hayas nombrado con el mismo nombre de los objetos del case 1 y case 2 respectivamente, no significan que sean iguales son nuevas instancias de sus respectivas clases y por ende no poseen datos..

Comment: Gracias, ya me quedo el concepto más claro. Bendiciones.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema es que estás un poco confundido respecto a los scopes.
Se podría decir que el scope es la región en las que ciertas variables pueden ser ocupadas.
Tomando como ejemplo lo siguiente:

```
public void testScope(){
    int[] scopeDeFuncion = new int[4];
    for(int i = 0;i < 5; i++) {
        int[] scopeAnidadoUno = new int[4];
        scopeDeFuncion[i] = i;
        for(int j = 0;j < 5; j++) {
            int[] scopeAnidadoDos = new int[4];
            scopeAnidadoUno[j] = j;
        }
    }
}
```

Tomando como ejemplo, el código de arriba, veemos una variable llamada `scopeAnidadoUno`. Esta variable se encuentra dentro de la función, pero no puede ser usada en toda la función, pues solo existe dentro del `scope` del primero for, por lo que cada iteración que pase se estará asignando nuevamente en memoria, es decir los datos no persistirán. Por lo tanto, `scopeAnidadoUno` solo puede ser usada en todo el scope del primer for, es decir solo en esta parte.

```
for(int i = 0;i < 5; i++) {
    int[] scopeAnidadoUno = new int[4];
    scopeDeFuncion[i] = i;
    for(int j = 0;j < 5; j++) {
        int[] scopeAnidadoDos = new int[4];
        scopeAnidadoUno[j] = j;
    }
}
```

Si intentamos hacer algo como esto

```
public void testScope(){
    int[] scopeDeFuncion = new int[4];
    for(int i = 0;i < 5; i++) {
        int[] scopeAnidadoUno = new int[4];
        scopeDeFuncion[i] = i;
        for(int j = 0;j < 5; j++) {
            int[] scopeAnidadoDos = new int[4];
            scopeAnidadoUno[j] = j;
        }
    }
    scopeAnidadoUno[0] = 1000;
}
```

Nos dará un error, ya que estamos llamando una variable fuera de su scope.

Un **scope** puede tener otro **scope** dentro, como es el caso del primer `for`, que tiene un segundo `for` dentro (un scope anidado). Las variables del **scope** padre se pueden usar el **scope** hijo, pero las variables del **scope** hijo no pueden usarse en el **scope** padre.

Teniendo esto ya aclarado, podemos ver en tu código

```
case 1:
    Medicamentos unMedicamento = new Medicamentos();
    unMedicamento.ingresarDatos();
    unMedicamento.calcularMedicamentos();
    unMedicamento.mostrarDatos();
    System.out.println(op2);
break;
```

Que el scope es solamente el case. Una vez que el case termina tu variable `unMedicamento` desaparece, porque su **scope** se ha terminado de ejecutar.

Para que persista, simplemente tienes que declararla en el scope correcto.

```
case 1:
    Regimen unRegimen = new Regimen();
    unRegimen.ingresarDatos();
    unRegimen.setContribucion();
    unRegimen.mostrarDatos();
    // Declarados en el scope del case del submenu.
    Laboratorios unLaboratorio = new Laboratorios();
    Medicamentos unMedicamento = new Medicamentos();
    int op2;
    do{
        Scanner teclado3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(" FACTURACION DE SERVICIOS DE SALUD");
        System.out.println(" 1.Facturacion medicamentos");
        System.out.println(" 2.Facturacion laboratorios");
        System.out.println(" 3. Terminar servicio de facturacion");
        System.out.println(" Digite opcion");
        op2 = teclado3.nextInt();
        switch(op2){
            case 1:
                unMedicamento.ingresarDatos();
                unMedicamento.calcularMedicamentos();
                unMedicamento.mostrarDatos();
                System.out.println(op2);
            break;
            case 2:
                unLaboratorio.ingresarDatos();
                unLaboratorio.calcularLaboratorios();
                unLaboratorio.mostrarDatos();
                System.out.println(op2);
            break;
            case 3:
                int suma;
                unMedicamento.darDatos();
                unLaboratorio.darDatos();
                suma = unMedicamento.darDatos()+ unLaboratorio.darDatos();
                System.out.println("El valor de todo sus servicios hasta el momento es :"+suma);
         
                
                
        }
    }
    while(op2 == 1 || op2 == 2);

break;
```

Si te das cuenta, se ha declarado los objetos de `unMedicamento` y `unLaboratorio` en un scope de un nivel más arriba, por lo que hasta que acabe el case donde se genero (el case acaba hasta que seleccionas 3 y sale del bucle. Tus objetos seguirán con la información que le has agregado.

Comment: Gracias, mil gracias. Ya me ha quedado más claro el concepto. Que la vida te lo retribuya al mill.